# Square Boxes with text aligned outside the box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing an issue in css styling. I am expecting a 3 square boxes with text which should appear just outside the box(rightside).

I have code like this

```
<div class="red">Closed</div>
<div class="yellow">Open</div>
<div class="blue">Pending</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
#red{
width: 25px;height: 20px;background: red;display: inline-block;
}
#yellow{
width: 25px;height: 20px;background: red;display: inline-block;
}

#blue{
width: 25px;height: 20px;background: red;display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

The ouput i got was:

[image: error image]

my expected output is

[image]

i dont want my text to appear inside the box.  i want the text to appear rightside(outside) of the box.

Comment: Links are dead, please re-update

Comment: background color is red, yellow, blue, respectively. In code it was mistakenly red for all div.

Comment: which link you are talking about sir?

Comment: He is talking about images which is uploaded by you in your question for output!

Comment: It's okay now,  don't worry about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you expect the text to end up outside?

Anyway:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: center;
  margin: 0 4px -10%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.red:before {
  background-color: #E30021;
}

.yellow:before {
  background-color: #FBC228;
}

.blue:before {
  background-color: #2B9BE3;
}
```

```html
<div class="red box">Closed</div>
<div class="yellow box">Open</div>
<div class="blue box">Pending</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2):

When your text is inside the element that has the background colour on it - I'm unsure why you think the outcome would be different.

```css
.key {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.key span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: #000;
}

.red span {
  background: red;
}

.yellow span {
  background: yellow;
}

.blue span {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="key red"><span></span>Closed</div>
<div class="key yellow"><span></span>Open</div>
<div class="key blue"><span></span>Pending</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `#` to `.` in your code, then try this.

```css
.wrapper {
  float: left;
}

.red {
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.yellow {
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

.blue {
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="red"></div>
    Closed
    <div class="yellow"></div>
    Open
    <div class="blue"></div>
    Pending
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```css
#red {
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#yellow {
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#blue {
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="red"></div><span>Closed</span>
<div id="yellow"></div><span>Open</span>
<div id="blue"></div><span>Pending</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this :

```css
/* BLOCK */
.block {
  display: inline-block;
}
.block .content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* BOX */
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.box-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.box-green {
  background-color: green;
}
.box-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="box box-red"></div> 
  <div class="content">Text</div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="box box-green"></div>
  <div class="content">Text</div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="box box-blue"></div>
  <div class="content">Text</div>
</div>
```

You need to use display: inline-block if you want to align div correctly.